# How do i divide a string at certain char value and than get the last word of this division?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This piece of code is from my dialogue system and in that part i want to split the string of the dialogue when the string is too big, but i don't want to divide the word in the middle, i would like to catch the entire word.

```
 List<string> a = new List<string>();

        if (actualInformation.text.Length > maxCharDisplayed) //Creat Chunks
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < actualInformation.text.Length; i += maxCharDisplayed)
            {
                if ((i + maxCharDisplayed) < actualInformation.text.Length)
                    a.Add(actualInformation.text.Substring(i, maxCharDisplayed));
                else
                    a.Add(actualInformation.text.Substring(i));
            }
        }else
        {
            a.Add(actualInformation.text);
        }
```

if someone could help me i'll be really thankfull!

Comment: It would be easier if you started at the max length and then worked backward.

Comment: can you help me with one exemple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to create a substring based on the max length, then find the index of the last space. If the index is less than zero, then there was no space found and we just have to cut off the word. Otherwise, use that substring, remove it from the text, and continue on:

```
var text = actualInformation.text;

while (text.Length > maxCharDisplayed)
{
    // Set cutoff to the last space before max length
    var cutoff = text.Substring(0, maxCharDisplayed).LastIndexOf(' ');

    // If no space was found, then we have no choice but to use the max length
    if (cutoff < 1) cutoff = maxCharDisplayed;

    // Add our substring to the list
    a.Add(text.Substring(0, cutoff));

    // Set our text to now start at the end of the substring we just added
    text = text.Substring(cutoff);
}

// Add whatever text is remaining.
a.Add(text);
```

---

@Abion47 had a few suggestions that I've implemented below (to also look for punctuation to split on, and to trim whitespace from the ends of the lines):

```
var charsToSplitOn = new[] 
{' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '.', ',', ';', ':', '-', ')', '}', '_'};

while (text.Length > maxCharDisplayed)
{
    var cutoff = text.Substring(0, maxCharDisplayed - 1)
                     .LastIndexOfAny(charsToSplitOn) + 1;
    if (cutoff < 1) cutoff = maxCharDisplayed;

    a.Add(text.Substring(0, cutoff).Trim());
    text = text.Substring(cutoff).Trim();
}

if (text.Length > 0) a.Add(text);
```

Comment: What about if you also want to split on punctuation (like a hyphen)?

Comment: @Abion47 Then set `cutoff` to the greatest value of `LastIndexOf` for each `charsToSplitOn`.

Comment: You could also use `LastIndexOfAny` and pass in a `char[]`. Also, I'd recommend using `TrimStart` on the second `Substring` so the split space doesn't bleed into the next line.

Comment: Ok, makes sense for display purposes. But you're adding requirements that weren't specified...it would also be nice to add a hyphen for words that can be hyphenated if necessary  :)

Comment: OP doesn't specify which characters they want to split a line on, only that they don't want to split in the middle of a word. Also, I can't imagine any game dialogue system where it would look visually pleasing to have lines randomly appear with a leading space. In either case, I am anticipating OP's needs.

Comment: @Abion47 Fair enough, I updated the answer for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve this problem is to divide messages into separate words, then count the number of characters in a group of words and if it is greater than the required value, wrap the last word on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about doing this. Personally, I'd use a `while` loop.

```cs
var list = new List<string>();
var input = actualInformation.text;

while (input.Length > maxCharDisplayed) 
{
    for (int i = maxCharDisplayed; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(input[i])) // Or whatever criteria
        {
            list.Add(input.Substring(0, i).TrimEnd());
            input = input.Substring(i).TrimStart();
            break;
        }
    }
            
    // The line is unbreakable at whitespace or punctuation, so break up the word
    list.Add(input.Substring(0, maxCharDisplayed));
    input = input.Substring(maxCharDisplayed);
}

list.Add(input);
```